# Problems with Linked list in C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm completely new to C++ and am breaking my head over a simple problem. I am trying to implement a simple linked list with three nodes. Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node(){
  int data;
  struct node* next;
};

struct node* BuildOneTwoThree() {
  struct node* head = NULL;
  struct node* second = NULL;
  struct node* third = NULL;

  head = new node;
  second = new node;
  third = new node;

  head->data = 1;
  head->next = second;

  second->data = 2;
  second->next = third;

  third->data = 3;
  third->next  = NULL;

  return head;

};
```

The question obviously being, why does it not compile? :(

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: What is the compiler error message?

Comment: If you're "completely new", then please expunge `abusing namespace std;` from your mind right now while you still have a chance, and never use it again.

Comment: Here is a copy of the error message(s): http://chopapp.com/#fq7vcb86

Comment: @user1200428: I don't think that's the first error message you got.

Comment: If you can, use the standard library's `std::list` instead of creating your own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the "()" from the struct declarations. Your compiler should have told you that.

Comment: Oh well yes - glad to have helped, and please take Kerrek SB's advice seriously and remove the "using namespace std" while you still have the chance ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
struct node(){
  int data;
  struct node* next;
};
```

with

```
struct node{
  int data;
  struct node* next;
};
```

The extra paranthesis after the struct declaration are causing the error. The latter is the proper way of declaring a `struct` or a `class` in C++.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of your `struct` has an excess pair of parenthesis. When you remove them this this should be OK:

```
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`()` should be written after functions instead of struct/class name.